# "Command /usr/sbin/chown failed with exit code 1" when Archiving

Tags: ios, xcode, chown

I am trying to archive my first iOS 4.3 Application for iPhone and I always encounter this error:

```
Command /usr/sbin/chown failed with exit code 1
```

I have searched through various forums, trying solutions such as changing the Alternate Install Group (which I don't know what to change to), and turning on 'Skip Install'.

Comment: Can you open the log tab (the speak bubble tab), select the build log  and then expand the chmod line that is failing and include the full command and output in the question?

Answer (score 136):

As dumb as it sounds, in XCode 5.1.1, all I had to do was quit out and restart XCode just now. I know it's not much of an "answer" but it just worked for me.

Edit: this is still working as of July 2018 for folks.
Edit: this is still working as of January 2019 xcode 9.4.1
Edit: this is still working as of February 2023 xcode 14.2

Comment: This is a bug with Xcode (still going strong in 8, apparently!)—in my case, it had incorrect values from another project I had open in the `Install Owner` and `Alternate Install Owner` fields.  As others have said, quitting Xcode, restarting it, and doing the clean and clean build folders procedures fixed it for me.

Comment: I'm not sure how many times I've come here to find this answer but based on my browser history this appears to be the 3rd time. This still works in 10.2.1. If someone wants to actually fix this, my issue is that chown fails because my company is using AD group names like "CORP\Domain Users" which is not a valid name.

Comment: Xcode 11.3.1, still works. However, with a twist. I had no problem when I was using my MacBook at work, but would get this error when I tried to archive while at home. BUT-- it would then work fine if I VPN'd to our work server from home. Very weird.

Comment: 2022, XCode 14, still working

Comment: Xcode 13.2.1 , fixed by restarting Xcode.

Comment: Xcode 14.3.1, Same fix: just restart, and maybe clean build folder too. But yes, it works!

Comment: I can confirm that it's still working on xcode 13.1 on Oct 2023

Answer (score 87):

[image]

I was having difficulty with the SetOwnerAndGroup part of Archiving - I was getting /usr/sbin/chown failed, and it was getting 'operation not permitted' on each file it tried to 'chown'.

This was easily tested in the terminal - 'chown' doesn't work, but 'sudo chown' does.  Since I had no need to be changing file permissions, the simplest solution was to not do the chown.

The screenshot above shows - I just blanked out Install Owner/Group, and that did it.

Comment: Also make sure that when you have any subprojects/libraries in your project (i.e. CordovaLib), to also blank out the Install Owner/Group there.

Comment: thanks this was exactly what I needed! But Im wondering why I need this. Yesterday it worked, today not. Of course I had also to blank out the _Install Permissions_

Comment: If in a corporate environment this can happen and this posting fixes it.  Top notch.

Comment: Normally I wouldn't think doing this step should be necessary, but it does fix the problem. I've come back to this answer a couple times.

Comment: yes indeed. After trying a few other things this was the problem solver.

Comment: I had the similar issue. This helped like a charm.

Answer (score 61):

When I got this error, rebooting my computer fixed it.

Comment: Rebooting was the only thing that fixed it for me as well.

Comment: Doesn't fix it.

Answer (score 24):

I have tried all the other solutions but none of them worked for me. So I have run this on a terminal to change the owner to me on every file in my project:

```
sudo chown -R my_username:my_group ./my_project_folder
```

where "my_username" is you username, "my_group" is your group (this is usually staff) and "my_project_folder" your project's folder.

Answer (score 6):

None of the other solutions worked for me on Xcode 4.5. What I had to do was the following:

The fix is by removing the armv6 architecture from both your project and the CordovaLib project, clean
both projects, and rebuild.

[Source](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CB-1497)

Comment: To elaborate these steps: in Xcode, click on your project, go to Build Settings tab, under Architectures there must be only armv7 written. Do the same for the CordovaLib project (it's in the left pane, the same as your project). Than clean both projects using Product -> Clean.

This worked for me also, fixed my problem.

Answer (score 2):

To it works in my environment I cleaned all information about permission, as +[adalle said](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11805109/1585438), complemented by [Tom](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7018783/command-usr-sbin-chown-failed-with-exit-code-1-when-archiving?answertab=votes#comment20917510_11805109) and [Phil](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7018783/command-usr-sbin-chown-failed-with-exit-code-1-when-archiving?answertab=votes#comment24159598_11805109)

I **emptied** the fields **Install Group**, **Install Owner**, **Install Permission**  including the ***Cordova SubProject***

Answer (score 2):

[image]I had the same issue with Xcode . It started working after restarting Xcode.
In the screenshot , Xcode ->build settings , installed group was empty after restarting Xcode .the group id it has showed as some number.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this is the same problem you are having, but this fixed it for me:

When I created my XCode project, my app name had a space in it, so trying to deploy my app always failed. I was able to fix this by using a `Custom Archive Name`.

In XCode 4...

1. Edit the Deployment Scheme
2. Click on the Archive tab
3. Then specify an Archive Name that doesn't have spaces in it.

[image: Specify a Custom Archive Name]

Answer (score 1):

I tried all possible variants and they didn't help me. So I downloaded old XCode 4.4.1 and voila - application archived successfully :)

Answer (score 1):

1. Select the target that's giving you the error
2. Change `Build Active Architecture Only` from Yes to No

That worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

For me reboot my mac fixed it. OS High Sierra, xCode 9.2

Answer (score 0):

When this happens to me on Xcode 8, I do "Clean build folder" 2 times (the first time it throws an error, but the second time succeeds) and then archive again.

Note: The "Clean build folder" option is under "Product" Menu, hold the alt button and you will see the "Clean" option changing to "Clean build folder".

Answer (score 0):

- Clean your project.
- Clean your build Folder. (Product > ⌥ > Clean Build Folder)
- Set the target device to Generic iOS Device .

[image]