# Error while generating ipa file + IOS app development

Tags: ios, xcode, ios5, ios6

> **Possible Duplicate:**
> [“Command /usr/sbin/chown failed with exit code 1” when Archiving](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7018783/command-usr-sbin-chown-failed-with-exit-code-1-when-archiving)

I am trying to generate ipa file(for IOS 6 or less) in xcode 4.5.2 with device having IOS 5.1. When I do product/Archive I get a fatal error:

```
Command /usr/sbin/chown failed with exit code 1
```

So, is it necessary for me to upgrade my device OS to 6.0 to generate ipa file for IOS 6 or less.

Answer (score 0):

That's very Strange. Are you using the newest XCode Version?

You could try to make a reboot, give your Archive a Custom Archive Name, Check in the Terminal if the Xcode Project matches the User with what you open the Xcode Project, Check the Install Owner in the Build Settings or try a Project Clean....